# Cannot rebind an imported name in python 3

Tags: python, import, variable-assignment

I am quite new to Python. Here is a problem that I have encountered while writing a program.

I am trying to re-bind a name of an imported function in Python 3:

E.g.

```
from module import imported_function
...
imported_function = function(5)
```

However, I am unable to do it for some reason. The imported_function in the module and the non-module one are called functions:

```
imported_function = another_function(2)
```

Sidenote: here, another_function(2) is a function that is defined outside the module.
Imported_function keeps giving me the imported_function from the module, even after the assignment statement imported_function = function(5).

I am not sure what is happening. Do import statements have higher priority in assignment?

Comment: Please explain more detailed what you do, expect and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can use `import ... as` in your case. For instance, if you want the `imported_function` to be `another_function` then do this:

```
from module import imported_function as another_function

another_function(...)
```

Or you can reassign your function to another name:

```
another_function = imported_function
```

However, if you do this:

```
another_function = imported_function(2)
```

Depending on the definition of the imported_function it will return the 
value or None to the variable another_function. Parentheses are important.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am using the name imported_function as the input of a higher-order function. I need the function represented by the name imported_function to be able to change.

Comment: @QuantumAMERICCINO What do you mean to be able to change for the imported_function? In python everything is an object. You can pass your imported fucntion as a parameter to another function.